# How to split string into multiple in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring

I'm Having a column data like below,

```
126-35-56-24
```

And I want the results be like,

```
select 126 as Id, 35 as Age, 56 as EmpId, 24 as Day
```

I just try using `substring` and I can Able to split the string into 126 and 35-56-24, but I can't get the result I Want.

Please help me to get this. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Use `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2016 or later, otherwise you'll need a custom function or a really ugly query with substring and other stuff.

Comment: To make your life easier, see if you can split your date data before you load it into SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below script ,which will split the strings based on the char index of  '-'.

```
DECLARE @data varchar(50)='126-35-56-24'

SELECT 'SELECT '+ SUBSTRING(@data,1,CHARINDEX('-', @data)-1) + ' as Id, '
   +SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX('-', @data)+1,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data) + 1) -CHARINDEX('-', @data)-1)+ ' as Age, '
   +SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data)+1)+1) -CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data)+1)-1)+' as EmpId, '
   +SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data)+1)+1)+1,LEN(@data)-CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-', @data,CHARINDEX('-',@data)+1)+1)+1) +' as Day'
```

Sample output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for the effort, But the data size may variant. It may like '66-35-546-4'., So I want to split by using the '-' only. Thank you..

Answer (score 6):

You could use [parsename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) if it's always 4 sets of data.

I simply replaced the - with a . and let parsename do the rest.

```
SELECT PARSENAME(Replace(Col,'-','.'), 1) AS 'Object Name' ID,    
       PARSENAME(Replace(Col,'-','.'), 2) AS 'Age',  
       PARSENAME(Replace(Col,'-','.'), 3) AS 'EmpID',  
       PARSENAME(Replace(Col,'-','.'), 4) AS 'Day'
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has mentioned it, you can simply use the `PARSENAME` function.   It's been available in SQL Server for quite some time.   It has some limitations, but it will handle the task in the example you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below Script:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(50)='126-35-56-24'
SELECT [1] AS ID, [2] AS AGE,[3] AS EMPID,[4] as day
FROM  (SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4]
   FROM    
      (SELECT ID,VAL FROM Spliter(@VAR,'-')) AS B
   PIVOT (MAX(VAL) FOR ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
         ) AS A
  ) AS C
```

And for splitting:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Spliter
(
@delimited nvarchar(max),
@delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
 id int identity(1,1),
 val nvarchar(max)
)
 AS
 BEGIN
 declare @xml xml
 set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r>       </root>'

 insert into @t(val)
 select
 r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
 from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

 RETURN
 END
 GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that Tim mentioned..,

But if you need a splitter

```
Declare @String varchar(50) = '126-35-56-24'

Select ID    = max(case when Key_PS=1 then Key_Value else null end)
      ,Age   = max(case when Key_PS=2 then Key_Value else null end)
      ,EmpID = max(case when Key_PS=3 then Key_Value else null end)
      ,Day   = max(case when Key_PS=4 then Key_Value else null end)
 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'-')
```

Returns

```
ID    Age   EmpID   Day
126   35    56      24
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 you can use string_split function

```
declare @str varchar(20) = '126-35-56-24'

select  id = max(case when rn=1 then value else null end)
    ,age =  max(case when rn=2 then value else null end)
    ,empId =  max(case when rn=3 then value else null end)
    ,[Day] =  max(case when rn=4 then value else null end)
    from (select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn, value from string_split(@str, '-')) a
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: You can use custom split and replace string_split function.. Let me know if you do not have one..